# Typedef struct pointers correctly pointing to typedef struct (C)

Tags: c, multithreading, pointers, struct

I am attempting to save a malloc'd ptr in a global ptr so I can use it in another function. Ideally I would a smarter data structure around the global, but for now I'm just trying to get the global ptr to work.

In my lwp.h file I have the following definitions:

```
typedef struct threadinfo_st *thread;
typedef struct threadinfo_st {
   tid_t         foo1
   unsigned long foo2
   size_t        foo3
   rfile         foo4
   thread        foo5
   thread        foo6
   thread        foo7
   thread        foo8
} context;
```

Using this thread struct, I have two functions in my lwp.c file. In the first function I construct a malloc'd thread and then copy the data to the global ptr. Then in the second function I attempt to dereference the global ptr to receive my initally created thread. To confirm I am doing this correctly, I print out the ptr addresses at each step. Unfortunately I cannot seem to regain my original address, thus all my data in the second function is shifted

```
static thread headThread = NULL;

void create(){
    thread newThread = (thread) malloc( sizeof(thread));
    assert(newThread != NULL)
    // Assign junk to newThread
    printf("newThread is at: %p, headThread is at: %p\n", &newThread, &headThread);
    headThread = newThread;
}

void start(){
    thread newThread = headThread;
    printf("newThread is at: %p, headThread is at: %p\n", &newThread, &headThread);
}
```

Calling create() then start() in main prints out:

```
 newThread is at: 0x7ffdf085c5e0, headThread is at: 0x601890
 newThread is at: 0x7ffdf085c5d8, headThread is at: 0x601890
```

Resulting in all my data in the start() function's newThread to be shifted.

I also tried the following:

```
static thread *headThread = NULL;

void create(){
    thread newThread = (thread) malloc( sizeof(thread));
    assert(newThread != NULL)
    // Assign junk to newThread
    printf("newThread is at: %p, headThread is at: %p\n", &newThread, &headThread);
    headThread = &newThread;
}

void start(){
    thread newThread = headThread;
    printf("newThread is at: %p, headThread is at: %p\n", &newThread, &headThread);
}
```

This prints out:

```
newThread is at: 0x7ffff6294130, headThread is at: 0x601890
newThread is at: 0x7ffff6294128, headThread is at: 0x601890
```

Does anyone know what exactly I am doing wrong in this scenario? 
Appreciate your help!

Comment: `thread newThread = (thread) malloc( sizeof(thread))` makes no sense. You're trying to allocate a struct, not a pointer, so `sizeof(thread)` is wrong. Better: `thread newThread = malloc(sizeof *newThread);` Best: Don't hide pointers behind typedefs.

Comment: Thank you, I'm working off of a header file that is provided to me for a multithreading assignment. I'll bring this up to my professor as to why he chose to structure it in this fashion. Appreciate your help!

Comment: Please do not remove the content from your questions. Your question stays, otherwise the answers don't make sense. Old revisions of your questions are still visible on the site, just hidden from the default view. If you've accidentally posted confidential data, you can have it removed, but first you need to **edit your question in such a way that the existing answers still make sense**, then flag your question and ask to have old revisions erased — but keep in mind they've already been indexed by Google. I don't see anything confidential-looking in your original question though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

int both functions start() and create() you are printing the address of:

the global variable headThread which is &headThread=0x601890 and remain unchanged because its the same every time (global)

but the variable  newThread  is declared locally (in the stack) to each of the two functions.

newThread in start() is not that in create(), they have different addresses in memory (stack) 0x7ffff6294130 is not 0x7ffff6294128.

to get the malloced ptr do this:

```
printf("newThread is at: %p, headThread is at: %p\n", newThread, headThread);
```

then this is the correct one :

```
static thread headThread = NULL;
```

not this:

```
static thread *headThread = NULL;
```

finally correct malloc to be as this:

```
thread newThread = malloc( sizeof(threadinfo_st)); //better use calloc
```

Comment: With the newThread in the start function, any time I try and access any of the fields I get a stack overflow error. How would I get around this?

Comment: you have to provide the full code. stack overflow let us think there is a recursive function that generate the error. but only by providing the full code to be sure

Answer (score 0):

As melpomene correctly pointed out you are allocating a pointer to context (which you call thread), not the context itself.

Then, in both fucntions you are printing addresses of where those pointers are stored (not the pointers itself). So, for static object (headThread) they are the same, for auto object (newThread, which is allocated on the stack each time anew) they are different.
What seems to be the problem here?